# why the numpy.size function is acting weird?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a matrix, named **X_test**, generated from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`. When I perform the following functions:

```
                import numpy as np
                np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
                print(X_test.shape)
                print(X_test.size)
                print(X_test.ndim)
                print(np.array(X_test))
```

I get:

```
  (10211, 218904)
  477881
  2
  (0, 934)  14
  (0, 6773) 1
  (0, 11035)    1
  (0, 22362)    1
  (0, 23619)    1
  (0, 24812)    1
  (0, 25224)    1
  : :
  (0, 64428)    1
  (0, 66506)    1
```

I don't know why the size is not the product of the matrix dimensions (shape).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result from `CountVectorizer` is a `scipy.sparse` matrix, not a NumPy array. On such a matrix, `np.size` reports the number of actually stored elements, which can be (should be) far smaller than the product of the `shape`.

(Also, to convert it to an array, use the `toarray` method, but be aware that you'd be creating an array several GB in size instead of the few MB used for the sparse format.)